# Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

Here is the code I am using.

```
if (appDatabase == null) {
        byte[] passEncryptionKey = encryptText();
        SafeHelperFactory factory = new SafeHelperFactory(passEncryptionKey);
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, KioskEngineDatabase.class, "dbname")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries().openHelperFactory(factory).build();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading your sqlcipher version to

```
implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar'
```

may solve your problem.

**Edit:** it seems you are trying to encrypt your room database using saferoom. this [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom/issues/43) may help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply but i am using cwac-saferoom lib to encrypt the db so that i can not use zetetic implementation

Comment: The link was dead, please update it appropriately.